# Convert List<object> to Dictionary<propertyname,propertyvalue>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary

I am trying to convert database results into a dictionary of type  Property name,   property value.

```
IEnumerable<image> results = Entity.GetAllContent<image>();

Dictionary<string, object> dict =
            results.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToDictionary(
                prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(results, null));
```

The line  Entity.GetAllConent is just an overload for ormlite select.   Normally this would return a generic list of multiple objects ( image ).    However when I try to do the above code,  its like it is trying to convert a list or IEnumerable to a dictionary, rather than converting the base type.

I get the following exception:

```
Parameter count mismatch.

     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Web.Controllers.HomeController.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1(PropertyInfo prop) in d:\projects\lovelife\Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 33
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at Web.Controllers.HomeController.Test() in d:\projects\lovelife\Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

no inner exception is provided.

Comment: I would put money on the Parameter Count mismatch coming from the GetValue method call.  Especially after looking at that callstack.  One of the parameters being provided by `GetParameters` is likely a list, or otherwise indexed, parameter, and GetValue needs that second parameter to be non-null in order to reference it correctly.

Comment: Im trying to understand your end goal here a little better:  Are you trying to convert the contents of the IEnumerable/List into a Dictionary?  (Dictionary would be type <String, Image>)....or are you trying to convert the actual definition of the Ienumerable, rather than its contents, into a dictionary object...Meaning that you need to define the properties of the collection so that it can be re-constituted from that defintion, including the data?

Comment: I think the later, however.   I think as below, and as i suspected.  How I am trying is impossible.   It may be that i have to create a wrapper for my class, with a list of type images, and pass that as one single record.  Its all for the DotLiquid stuff, but the guy who made it did a tiny hard coded tutorial, that does not give many clues out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is going to work.  You have a list of the same type of object (`image`).  Each one is going to have the same properties (perhaps Id, Name, etc).  How are you going to put them all in one dictionary?  You would have duplicate keys for each one.  You need to rewrite it to create a list of dictionaries, 1 for each element.

```
var dictionaries = results.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                          .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(x, null)))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: its because I am trying to use dotliquid,   but the developers there dont answer anything, or provide real world case.   I have to pass over a dictionary<string,object>, however the liquid template code allows for a loop / for each.    so for this i would need a collection.   I know what you are saying above, and this is the problem as I am thinking the same, makes no sense that they want a dictionary of multiple instances of the same class ????

Comment: You must be confused about what they want.  It's physically not possible to have a dictionary with identical keys.

Comment: Yes trevor my thoughts too, just needed to check it was not me that was missing some magic voodoo or something.   I think in this case I have to wrap my List inside a holding class with List<T> Values  and then send that wrapper as one request.  IN liquid i should be able to loop through  classname.values, rather than classname

Comment: going to mark this as answer, although not a solution, U have confirmed my initial findings and helped me to re-think how i tackle this matter